# Identify regions of zeros that are surrounded by ones in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, pixel, raster, r-raster

I have a list of binary matrices. In each matrix, I want to detect regions of white pixels (`0`) surrounded by ring (a chain) of connected black pixels (`1`).

For example, in the matrix below, there are two regions of white pixels (zeros) both entirely surrounded by a "chain" of connected 1s: the 2x2 and the 3x2 group of 0s.

```
m
#         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#    [1,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    1
# -> [2,]    1    0    0    1    1    1    1
# -> [3,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1 <- 
#    [4,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    1 <- 
#    [5,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1 <-
#    [6,]    0    1    1    1    1    1    1

m <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
              1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
              1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
              1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
              1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
              0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
            byrow = TRUE, nrow = 6)
```

---

An example with three binary matrices in a `list`:

```
set.seed(12345)
x <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 15)

set.seed(9999)
y <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 15)

set.seed(12345)
z <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 15)

mat_list <- list(x, y, z)
```

I have thought of using the `boundaries` function in the `raster` package, so I start by converting the matrices to raster:

```
library(igraph)
library(raster)

lapply(list, function (list) {
  Rastermat <- raster(list)
})
```

---

Any guidance on how I could implement this would be appreciated.

---

Comment: You provide a nice clear sample of data, but could you explain what you mean by "region of white pixels surrounded by a ring of black pixels?" Are you looking to tally the groups of connected white pixels as regions? If so, how many points of contact between pixels define a define a connection? Or are you looking to exclude white pixels that contact the border?

Comment: @DavidO I have added a bit more of an explanation as well as an example hope that helps!

Comment: @Z.Rodgers Can you please explain how you "would expect to have 4 regions" in your example matrix. I see _two_ groups of zeros "surrounded by ring (a chain) of connected black pixels": the 4*3 group and the 5*2 group. The 4*1 group has a zero at one diagonal, the two groups at the top and bottom row are clearly not surrounded...

Comment: @Henrik you're right there is two groups of 0s when you take into account what you said. I have edited :)

Comment: In addition, I suppose your _main_ issue here is to determine the regions in _one_ matrix. Once that is solved, you can easily apply that solution to `list` of several matrices. Thus, I would focus the question on one matrix only (like your last toy matrix) and remove the list stuff (that would be a separate problem, which you seem to know how to solve anyway (your `lapply` approach)). ;) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REVISED ANSWER** for new information.

For this answer, the definition of connected pixels is a bit more than that used for image processing. Here, pixels are considered connected if they share a side as `{x,y}` and `{x+1,y}` or `{x,y}` and `{x,y+1}` or touch at a corner as `{x,y}` and `{x+1,y+1}`. It is possible that other packages (such as `igraph`) may be more efficient for this task, but `EBImage` can do the job with tools to visualize or further process the results.

The `bwlabel` function in the package `EBImage` is used here to find connected groups of pixels. As the authors describe it:

> `bwlabel` finds every connected set of pixels other than the background,
>   and relabels these sets with a unique increasing integer

This is part of the the Bioconductor package **[EBImage](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage/)**, which is an image processing and analysis toolbox for *R*. It's a bit big. The following code checks for availability and attempts to download and install the package if needed:

```
# EBImage needed through Bioconductor, which uses BiocManager
  if (!require(EBImage)) {
    if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
      install.packages("BiocManager")
    BiocManager::install("EBImage")
    require(EBImage)
  }
```

The `EBImage` tools allows you to extract connected pixels from binary images (considered objects) and quantify or visualize much about them. With apologies for any overkill, here's a **REPLACED** answer with a more extensive example that includes irregular objects to demonstrate the solution.

Typically, 0 is used for the absence of data in image processing so the data in the example uses 0 for non-data and 1 for data.

```
# Sample data with 1 as data, 0 as non-data
dat <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
         0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,
         0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,
         0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,
         0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,
         0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,
         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,
         0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
# convert to 20x20 pixel image object
  x <- Image(dat, dim = c(20, 20)) # use 1 for data, 0 for non-data
# plotting with base graphics allows the use of other R tools
  plot(x, interp = FALSE) # interpolate = FALSE option preserves pixels
```

Image representation of 20 x 20 binary array in `dat`.

[image: image representation of data]

```
# bwlabel() extracts connected pixels from a binary image
# and labels the connected objects in a new Image object
  xm <- bwlabel(x)
  xm # show the first 5 rows, first 6 columns of "objects" identified by bwlabel
> Image 
>   colorMode    : Grayscale 
>   storage.mode : integer 
>   dim          : 20 20 
>   frames.total : 1 
>   frames.render: 1 
> 
> imageData(object)[1:5,1:6]
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
> [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
> [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
> [3,]    0    0    0    0    4    4
> [4,]    1    1    0    0    4    4
> [5,]    1    1    0    0    4    4
```

The number of objects (connected pixels) found is simply the maximum value in the object returned by `bwlabel`. The size of each object (connected pixels) is easy to get by the `table` function. This information can be extracted and used to prepare a labeled image. This examples includes an object with a hole.

```
# total number of objects found
  max(xm) 
> 9

# size of each object (leaving out background or value = 0 pixels)
  table(xm[xm > 0])
>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
>  8 13 21 36 15  8  4  6 21 

# plot results with labels
  iy <- (seq_along(x) - 1) %/% dim(x)[1] + 1
  ix <- (seq_along(x) - 1) %% dim(x)[1] + 1

  plot(xm, interp = FALSE)
  text(ix, iy, ifelse(xm==0, "", xm)) # label each pixel with object group
```

[image: labeled objects]

There are five objects surrounded by a "chain" of connected background pixels: #3, #4, #6, #7 and #9. Object #6 is included even though it has a hole. The logic can be adjusted to exclude objects with holes. Objects #1 and #2 are to be excluded because they border the edge. Objects #5 and #8 are to be excluded because they touch at a corner. If this accurately represents the task, `EBImage` can still help with the logic enumerated below. In brief, a border around each object will be created and determined if it covers only blank (or non-border) pixels in the original image.

1. Extract each object found by `bwlabel` as a separate image (`xobj`)
2. Add a border of black (zero) pixels to each object in `xobj`
3. Dilate each object in `xobj` by one pixel with `EBImage::dilate` (`xdil`)
4. Create a difference mask with `xor` (`xmask`)
5. Add a non-zero border to the original image (`x2`)
6. Combine `xmask` and `x2` to identify borders that have non-blank pixels
7. Remove objects identified above

```
# Extract each object found by bwlabel() as a separate image
  xobj <- lapply(seq_len(max(xm)), function(i) xm == i)

# Add a border of black (zero) pixels to each object in `xobj`
  xobj <- lapply(xobj, function(v) cbind(0, rbind(0, v, 0), 0))
  xobj <- lapply(xobj, as.Image)
  xobj <- combine(xobj) # combine as multi-dimensional array

# Dilate each object in `xobj` by one pixel
  br <- makeBrush(3, shape = "box") # 3 x 3 structuring element
  xdil <- dilate(xobj, br)

# Create difference mask with xor()
  xmask <- xor(xdil, xobj) # difference is the border

# Add a non-zero border to the original image
  x2 <- Image(cbind(1, rbind(1, x, 1), 1))

# Identify borders that have non-blank pixels
  target <- Image(x2, dim = dim(xmask)) # replicate x2
  sel <- which(apply(xmask & target, 3, any) == TRUE)

# Remove objects identified above (keeping original numbers)
  found <- rmObjects(xm, sel, reenumerate = FALSE)

# Show the found objects
  table(found[found > 0])
>  3  4  6  7  9 
> 21 36  8  4 21
```

Each of the objects can be examined by plotting. Multi-dimensional images such as `xobj`, `xdil`, and `xmask` can be plotted with `plot(xobj, all = TRUE, interp = FALSE)` to see the intermediate results. Here, the filtered (found) objects are 
re-plotted with the original object numbers

```
  plot(found, interp = FALSE)
  text(ix, iy, ifelse(found==0, "", found)) # label each pixel group no.
```

[image: found objects]

To learn more about *EBImage* see the the package [vignette](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.html).

Comment: You're welcome and good luck. Your edit defines the task a little more clearly and makes it less like image processing. You want to exclude pixels on the boundary and **only** include data pixels surrounded entirely by non-data. My answer will have to change... :)

Comment: Completely revised answer that hopefully addresses the question! Good luck again.